# Show that $F(x) = f(\|x\|)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

> Let an even function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is even and differentiable. We define $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$  as $F(x) = f(\|x\|)$. Show that $F(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My Work:**

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. If $x_0\ne 0$ then the partial derivatives of the norm are well-defined and:
   $$ \frac{\partial \|.\|}{\partial x_i} = \frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$$
   $\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$ continuous and since $f$ is differentiable it's partial derivatives are continuous. So we can conclude that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}$ is continuous and therefore $F$ is differentiable.
2. If $x_0=0$ then the $\|x_0\| = 0$ and since $f$ is even $f(0)=0$ and it must be an extremum point. Therefore, $F'(0)=0$.

I'd like to get a critique of my work. Am I being right/rigorous?

Thanks.

Comment: $f(0)$ need not be $0$, but this is irrelevant to the problem (see $\cos$, for example). Justification of $f'(0) = 0$ and $DF(0) = 0_{n\times n}$ in 2. is missing.

Comment: To add to AlexR's comment, the main item to check is that _$F$ is differentiable at the origin_. (This isn't obvious, because the norm function is _not_ differentiable at the origin.) You'll need both evenness and differentiability of $f$ to conclude $DF(0)$ exists.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658660/multivariate-differentiability-verification/663191#663191.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the case $x_0 \neq 0$ is correct and trivial, your proposed solution for the case $x_0=0$ is not a proof at all. A function can have a maximum or minimum at a point where it is not smooth (e.g. $x \mapsto |x|$ in $\mathbb{R}$).

Here you should use the fact that $f'(0)=0$ (because $f$ is even and differentiable at zero), so that
$$
f(t)=f(0)+o(t) \quad\hbox{as $t \to 0$}. \tag{1}
$$
Now plug $t=\|x\|$ into $(1)$ and deduce that
$$
F(x)=F(0)+o(\|x\|) \quad\hbox{as $x \to 0$},
$$
which shows that $DF(0)=0$.

Comment: Could you explain further why is it implying that $F'(0)$ exists? I thought about showing by the chain-rule that:

$$F'(x=0) = \left( f(\|x\|) \right) = D_f(\|x\|)\|x\|' = 0$$

Comment: It is the mere definition of differentiability at a point. You cannot use any chain rule, since the norm is not differentiable at the origin!

Comment: I know that in terms of limits, $F$ is differentiable at zero iff: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)-\langle D_f(0),x \rangle}{\|x\|} = 0$$

Comment: ...and you should realize that it is exactly the same.

Comment: Okay, thank you for connecting the dots! Cheers